# Keep users logged in across multisite in wordpress (for various domains)

Tags: multisite, login

I have following style domains in my multisite

- supersite.com (main site)
- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- a.domain1.com
- b.domain1.com

I would like to keep myself (and my users) logged in across all subsites, as long as they are registered to that subsite.

So, if I am a user of domain.com and a.domain1.com, I would like to keep myself logged in between two sites. Same goes for another user with accounts in domain1.com and domain2.com.

Let me share more a realistic scenario. For a user who is registered to a.domain1.com, for example, I have multisite sync plugin that automatically sign-up that user to b.doamin2.com, which is support forum page open to all registered users. Now that if the user, who is currently logged into a.domain1.com, he/she has to login again for b.domain2.com to write a Q/A on a support forum.

I thought below code to wp-config.php can solve the puzzle.

```
define(‘COOKIE_DOMAIN’, ‘.domain1.com’)
```

But it didn't. I still had to login to b.domain2.com. Even if it works, judging from other questions on StackExchange, it seems that I still need to find a way to keep login cookie between

- domain1.com
- domain2.com

When I had a single WP installation for a single domain, I've tried below

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] )
```

and I thought it should work for sub-domain only cases. If so, at least

- domain1.com
- a.domain1.com
- b.domain2.com

should share a single cookie. But none of the above cookie_domain setting options allowed me to share login between the sub-domains.